# Is it possible to update my dynamic webpage with real-time data with Flask and Socket.io?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, websocket, socket.io

I'd like to create a dynamic webpage that should communicate with a python script created by me. That script receives, analyses and updates data every second, i would like to send all this data to my webpage and update it every second to my webpage. Can i do that with Flask and Socket.io? Or is Flask enough to accomplish that?

Note that speed is an essential requirement for what i'm trying to do, since it updates data every second it needs to be accurate. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I encounter a page that refreshes itself every second I wont visit it for long ... what is so important that you need to serverfetch data every second?

Comment: I don't need the page to refresh every second, only need the part with the data to be updated, it's trading data

Comment: _Can i do that with Flask and Socket.io_ yes. _is Flask enough_ yes.